# Create custom WP Query for getting custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api

I need to create custom WP Query for getting custom post type, and it should be returned the first letter in each post title with a group.

The **brand** is a custom post type.

I have now created a list that is only showing A, B, E ... Z,

If no post title will start from **C** then not return **C** alphabet letter.

also, return special character and numeric numbers.

Comment: You did any r&d on this, do you have any code where you are getting error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'brand',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC' 
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_query->the_post();
$titleofpost = get_the_title(); 
$shorttitle = $titleofpost[0];
            ?>
            <h2><?php echo $shorttitle; ?></h2>
            <?php
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put in some template to view post with its first letter

Comment: Hi @Ravi, any other option, in wp_query $args. this is a way but there will be to much load because our brand created post is more than 5000+.

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio') ) );
```

which shows both normal posts and posts inside portfolio type

or

```
query_posts('post_type=portfolio');
```

for only **portfolio**.

Use as normal WP Query - read the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```